# C++ tuple of vectors, create tuple from elements by index

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I've got a template class, that has tuple, filled by vectors.

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> vectors;
};
```

I want to get new tuple filled by vectors element on the specified index.

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> vectors;

    std::tuple<Ts...> elements(int index)
    {
        // How can I do this?
    }
};
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to have a vector of tuples?

Comment: @LogicStuff Maybe for performance reason, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish it rather easily in C++14 it with the usual technique of a helper function that accepts an [index sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) as an added  parameter:

```
template<std::size_t... I> 
auto elements_impl(int index, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(
      std::get<I>(vectors).at(index)...
    );
}


auto elements(int index)
{
    return elements_impl(index, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

It just calls `std::get<I>` for the ordinal of each type, and then calls `at` on the vector at that place. I used `at` in case the vectors aren't all holding an item at that index, but you can substitute for `operator[]` if your case doesn't require the check. All the results are then sent to `make_tuple` to construct the result tuple object.